# SSDT Project build failure - Access denied to dacpac file in debug mode

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, build, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac

I am trying to build an SSDT project.  I get the following error message when I run 'build':

- Access to the path 'whateverMyPathIs\bin\debug\myProjectName.dacpac' is denied.
- 03061: Unable to delete file "whateverMyPathIs\bin\debug\myProjectName.dacpac". Access to the path 'whateverMyPathIs\bin\debug\myProjectName.dacpac' is denied.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

Things I have noticed:

- When I build the project in 'Release' mode I do not get the above error messages.
- I have tried using Process Explorer to see if the dacpac file is being used by any other process and have not been able to find anything.
- From Project Settings/Build, if I change the 'Build output path' from 'bin/debug' to somewhere else different, the build works fine.
- After restarting the machine I now get only the first error message about 'Access denied....'.  The error message starting with 03061 does not come up.

I am using Visual studio 2012, SQL 2000 R2, SSDT 2012

Answer (score 1):

With my colleague's help I resolved the issue by changing the 'Read-only' attribute from the parent folder of where the actual solution/project is saved.